# Python extract information after phrase or group of words

Tags: python, regex, extract

I am trying to extract information from PDF.

Simple search worked:

```
filecontent = ReadDoc.getContent("c:\\temp\\pdf_1.pdf")
match = re.search('Document ID: (\d+)', filecontent)
if match:
    docid = match.group(1)
```

But when I want to search a long phrase, e.g.
I want to extract '$999,999.00', which may appear in the document like "Total Cumulative Payment (USD) $999,999.00" or "Total cumulative payment $55587323.23". Note that there is a difference in the text and I need to use some kind of fuzzy search, find the sentence, somehow extract the $ from there.

Similarly I also need to extract some date, number, amount, money in between phrases/words.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: The question seems unrelated ro where the text comes from, so I'll remove the tag PDF. "NLTK" seems also a bit too broad for what you do.

Comment: My question was actually related to NLTK, how to extract something from a large document. But you are correct, not necessarily NLTK

Comment: The Natural Language Toolkit (Python library for computational linguistics) to which that tag refers, seemed excessively broad for your task, that's why. I am not sure about a pure regex solution; perhaps best is a combination with simple string matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want:

```
import re

textlist = ["some other amount as $32,4545.34 and Total Cumulative Payment (USD) $999,999.00 and such","Total cumulative payment $55587323.23"]

matchlist = []

for text in textlist:
    match = re.findall("(\$[.\d,]+)", text)
    if match:
        matchlist.extend(match)

print(matchlist)
```

results:

```
['$32,4545.34', '$999,999.00', '$55587323.23']
```

The regex is look for a $ and grab ., and numbers up to the next space.  Depending on what other kind of data you are parsing it may need to be tweaked, I assuming you only want to capture periods, commas and numbers.

update:

it will now find any number of occurrences and put them all in a list

Comment: thanks for trying! but if you any other amount in the same text, then it won't give your result. Run your code with this:

textlist = ["some other amount as $32,4545.34 and Total Cumulative Payment (USD) $999,999.00 and such","Total cumulative payment $55587323.23"]

Comment: give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks again, I am interested the amount after 'Total Cumulative Payment' . My original question is how can I extract 'Total Cumulative Payment' from a document

Answer (score 0):

Well something like this can be done with regular expressions:

```
import re

source = 'total cumulative payment $2000.00;   some other amount $1234.56.    Total Cumulative Payment (USD) $5,600,000.06'
matches = re.findall( r'total\s+cumulative\s+payment[^$0-9]+\$([0-9,.]+)', source, re.IGNORECASE )
amounts = [ float( x.replace( ',', '' ).rstrip('.') ) for x in matches ]
```

This will match the two specific examples you've given.  But you haven't given much of an idea of how loose the matching criteria should be, or what the rules are.  The solution above will miss amounts if the source document has a spelling mistake in the word "cumulative".  Or if the amount appears *without* the dollar sign.  It also allows *any* amount of intervening text between "total cumulative payment" and the dollar amount (so you'll get a false positive from `source = "This document contains information about total cumulative payment values, (...3 more pages of introductory material...) and by the way you owe me $20."`)   Now, these things can be tweaked and improved - but only if you know what is going to be important and what is not, and tighten the specification of the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, close to what I am looking for, got some threads, let me come back!